# How to send JSON response to Dojo table/grid

Tags: json, dojo, kendo-ui, dojox.grid.datagrid, kendo-treeview

Giving up on lack of support for a transpose option with the KendoGrid I'm looking for help on displaying a simple JSON (JSONP support as well) response in two columns (what I'm calling a transpose), property and attribute. See below my json for one record:

```
[
 {
  "Account Num": "12345",
  "Address": "1 MAIN ST",
  "City": "CEDAR",
  "Name_1": "JOHN ANDREWS",
  "Name_2": "",
  "Street": "TEMPLE ST",
  "State": "TX",
  "Zip": "12345-3217"  
 }
]
```

I need the functionality of being able to select the row (City: Cedar) in the dojo control so I can fire an event.

If you want to go an extra mile, I would replace the KendoTreeView with a Dojo one, if you have an example of the two controls wired up. The tree view has the "Name_1" results where you click to get a single record (above) and show the property and attribute results in the Dojo grid/table.

I'm so stuck on this and appreciate the help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Give a code example of what you have; this makes it much easier to see the problem and try to give an answer.

Comment: Thanks. I posted here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454009/treeview-and-resulting-clickable-pivot-table-functionality) with some of the info which may help. This example populates a KendoGrid just fine but due to it having so many columns the data scrolls horizontally. If I could put the data (example above) in two columns, "Account Num" in one and attribute "12345" in the second so you have a two-column vertical scroll of properties that would be great. The code I have now is KendoGrid. Let me know if the previous post helps and thank you.